# onBackPressed() not working for first time

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tablelayout, android-tabs

When I am opening a new activity from a tabview but on that activity onBackPressed() is not working for the first time[image]

more code detail added frist activity mean first iamge and second activity mean second image I am trying to do something else on back button press from second activity
**First Activity**

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();

    //finish();
    //Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Back pressed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getParent()); 

    alertDialog.setTitle("Confirm Exit ..."); 
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to exit ?"); 
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.tick); 

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            AppPreferenceStatus.setLoggedOutStatus(CurContext, true);
            finish();
            //System.runFinalizersOnExit(true);
            //System.exit(0);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
    }); 

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        dialog.cancel(); 
        } 
    }); 

    alertDialog.show();

}
```

**Second Activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some code.

Comment: can we have code please ?

Comment: The Toast line is commented